# C++ deleting first element in array of pointers effects later elements

Tags: c++, arrays, heap, delete-operator, sigabrt

For a lab assignment I'm working on an array implementation of a heap. I have an array of type `PrintJob *`. The issue I'm facing is that the first element `arr[0]` I try deleting with `delete` strangely modifies the second element of the array. Eventually that element makes its way to the head of the heap, and deleting it causes a SIGABRT.

I was originally thinking perhaps deleting it from the array directly, `delete arr[0]` was issuing some type of error since I would be repeatedly calling `delete arr[0]`; even though, I update `arr[0]` with its next greatest child immediately after deleting it. So, I tried storing it into a temporary variable and then deleting it:

```cpp
void dequeue() {
    PrintJob *temp = arr[0];
////    delete arr[0];
    trickleUp(0);
    delete temp;
}
```

But I soon realized my effort didn't make any sense. I know that a SIGABRT happens when the program tries deleting a dynamically allocated entity twice, but I never touch any other element except for the first. So I'm confused as to why the second element gets filled with junk values and later throws the SIGABRT.

Here's some other code I use:

This function is called by the function above, and controls the process of shifting current index's (`n`'s) greatest child to its position. It does this recursively as per requirement.

```cpp
void trickleUp(int n) {

    int c = getChild(n, true);  // get the greater child

    if (c >= MAX_HEAP_SIZE) {   // if the
        PrintJob *temp = arr[n];
////        delete arr[n];
        arr[n] = nullptr;
        delete temp;
        return;
    }

    arr[n] = arr[c];    // update the old node
    trickleUp(c); // move to the next element in the tree;
}
```

getChild() is a function called by the previous function designed to return the greatest child index (`ln`: left node, `rn`: right node) of the current index `n`.

```cpp
int getChild(int n, bool g) {

    int ln = (2 * n) + 1, rn = (2 * n) + 2, lp = -1, rp = -1;

    if (ln < MAX_HEAP_SIZE && arr[ln]) {
        lp = arr[ln]->getPriority();
    }

    if (rn < MAX_HEAP_SIZE && arr[rn]) {
        rp = arr[rn]->getPriority();
    }

    return  ( !((lp > rp) ^ g) ? ln:rn );
}
```

I've checked the code multiple times, and I haven't seen any other logical errors, of course, I won't be able to truly tell until this issue is resolved and I'm able to test with additional samples. Here's a link to all the rest of the code, if you'd like to compile it yourself. I've attached a makefile too.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18idHtRO0Kuh_AftJgWj3K-4OGhbw4H7T?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] within the question without external links.

Comment: `arr[n] = arr[c];` looks a little suspicious, you now have the same pointer stored in two different places?

Comment: That is until I update arr[c] with its next greatest child in the following line `trickleUp(c)`. Would you still suggest that I change it?

Comment: You'll need to debug your code but as you suspect double frees then the part of your code that duplicates pointers is likely to be a good starting point

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Failing that, I can offer baseless speculation and handwaving.

Comment: I also apologize for not keeping the program concise. I'll try to reproduce the problem in a smaller size as soon if possible. The only issue is this is due tomorrow, I understand that effectivity of people's help will be reduced considering the size of the code and amount of redundancy in regards to the problem. If there's still any suggestions or a similar hump that anyone has hit, and could provide a possible fix I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Instrumenting your code with some prints produces the following output:

```
set 0
set 1
set 2
set 3
set 4
swap 1, 4
swap 0, 1
copy 1 to 0
copy 4 to 1
delete 4
copy 2 to 0
copy 6 to 2
delete 6
copy 2 to 0
copy 6 to 2
delete 6
copy 2 to 0
copy 6 to 2
delete 6
copy 2 to 0
copy 6 to 2
delete 6
```

The numbers are the indexes into `arr`. If we add some names to these objects it might become clear what is going wrong:

```
set 0 - A
set 1 - B
set 2 - C
set 3 - D
set 4 - E
swap 1, 4 - 1 == E, 4 == B
swap 0, 1 - 0 == E, 1 == A
copy 1 to 0 0 == A, 1 == A, pointer to E is lost
copy 4 to 1 1 == B, 4 == B
delete 4    delete B, 4 == 0, 1 still points to B
copy 2 to 0 0 == C, 2 == C, pointer to A is lost
copy 6 to 2 2 == 0
delete 6    delete null pointer, has no effect
copy 2 to 0 0 == 0, 2 == 0, pointer to C is lost
copy 6 to 2 2 == 0
delete 6    delete null pointer, has no effect
the rest just further copies around null pointers
```

In this particular sample it doens't crash (for me at least) as nothing is deleted twice but hopefully its clear how that could happen with different data.

Presumably:

```
    arr[n] = arr[c];    // update the old node
```

should be:

```
    arr[c] = arr[n];    // update the old node
```

This then makes your code crash even faster though so there are probably further logic issues to be found.